# I can't enable binlog in MySQL

Tags: master-slave, mysql5

I am trying to enable binary log in order to create master slave for my DB.
MySQL version is 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.10-log
I have added this to my.cnf

```
log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days  = 1
max_binlog_size   = 100M
```

and

```
$ ls -l /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql root 0 2011-07-06 17:17 /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
```

Now when I try to stop/start MySQL the starting process goes forever and I was forced to comment those entries in my.cnf to start MySQL again.

Anybody faced such problem? Any idea is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you see anything of use in the server log `mysqld.log`?

Comment: If you can, > 'strace -Ff -v /etc/init.d/mysql
> start' and post output please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for your help
it was permission of the log directory itself. i have changed it to be

```
drwx------ 7 mysql mysql  4096 2011-07-06 20:06 mysql
```

it was

```
drwx------ 7 root root  4096 2011-07-06 20:06 mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a host_name-bin.index file created? If not, specify log-bin-index as well.